# Adding an option for valid questions in some lists

Tags: discussion, questions, filtering

I think it can be useful if we have an option for filtering valid questions in some lists that:

- Valid questions filter : `closed:no duplicate:no locked:no`
- Some lists: [ [`All Questions`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions), [`Top Questions`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), [`Unanswered Questions`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/unanswered) ]

I know that writing the above filter is not so hard; But I think it can make sense ;).
And I think this option should be checked as default.

Answer (score 2):

1 picture equals 1000 words:

> [image]

These days any decent browser let you add a bookmark with one simple step. Can't see any reason for SE to spend time on something anyone can do so easily.

Comment: For each SE sites, we will have at least 3 bookmarks, that I think it is not so good ;).

Comment: @shA.t well, you can have folders, still easy enough. :)